# Django request.session.save() authentication

Tags: python, django, django-models

Bit of a strange one and I have my reasons for doing this, I know Django does this out-of-the-box so put that to the side when I ask.....  is it possible to **create a authenticated session in Django for a user that does not exist in the standard user model.** i.e I want a one off login (session) created for access that allows me to use `request.tempUser.is_authenticated()` Almost like anonymous access, but authenticated! I'm **not** talking about custom user models here, but I want do want use the standard auth stuff in Django, if thats possible?

This is what I have so far where I have tried `request.session.save()` but that won't ... log-in the user.

```
if member.check_password(password):
            # Start new session for member???????
            request.session.save()
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': True
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before, we have a session middleware (we wrote) that looks to see if the current user logged in is a valid user or not.

On the login we do the following

```
def login(request, username, password):
    # not the actual code, but you get the gist
    logged_in_user = authenticate(username, password)
    request['cur_user'] = logged_in_user.username
```

If that variable is not set or is not set to a proper username we bounce the user and clear out the session.

This will *log* in the user, essentially you just have to track that variable in your code to ensure that the session has a valid user attached to it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. quick quick question is this still using the Django auth system to login? everytime I try I get "error_message": "'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'",

Comment: no, but that point you're writing your own auth system.  I can't think of any way to use your own auth object for a system expecting another.  You definitely can extend the auth system.